# Reading the string item from list of list python and understand how split() function works

Tags: python, arrays

I have list of list having string of words in following order: I am trying to extract each word from each list as a separate element.

```
list1=[["Milk,Bread,Butter"],["Milk,Bread,Butter"], ["Milk,Bread,Butter"],]
```

I used following code

```
for subList in List1():
    for ele in subList[0].split():
            print (ele)
```

Desired output is: Milk, Bread, Butter, Milk, Bread, Butter, Milk, Bread, Butter

However above code produces a complete list: [Milk, Bread, Butter]   [Milk, Bread, Butter]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```py
final = []
for sublist in list1: 
    for item in sublist[0].split(','):
        final.append(item)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. seems like, I have to check how spilt() function works. Apparently, if there was straight string in the list, e.g., [Milk Butter Bread], then, split() would do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, each sublist in `list1` has only one string, so you could simply print the first element:

```
for sublist in [["Milk,Bread,Butter"],["Milk,Bread,Butter"],["Milk,Bread,Butter"]]:
    print(sublist[0])
```

If you want them as a single string you could do:

```
list1 = [["Milk,Bread,Butter"],["Milk,Bread,Butter"], ["Milk,Bread,Butter"]]
res = ",".join([sublist[0] for sublist in list1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[item for items in [item[0].split(',') for item in list1] for item in items]
```

output:

```
['Milk',
 'Bread',
 'Butter',
 'Milk',
 'Bread',
 'Butter',
 'Milk',
 'Bread',
 'Butter']
```

Or if you can use numpy:

```
np.ravel([item[0].split(',') for item in list1]).tolist()
```